# NSWindow can't be centered

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I tried to center the position of the main window of my app, using in the first time Automatic Initial Position in IB, and then using `[window center]` but my app appears at the last location it was before closing. What's going on?

Comment: Did you set an frame autosave name? If so, unset it.

Comment: OSX seems to remember your window location and then restore it. Try catching the event when your app is invoked and then call `[window center]`.

Answer (score 0):

Window in my application always appears in center. You may compare my main window settings in IB:

[image]

[image]

hope it helps you